# How to give numbers to each group of a dataframe with dplyr::group_by?

Tags: r, group-by, functional-programming, dplyr

I want to give numbers to each group in a dataframe. For example, I have the following dataframe:

```
df = data.frame( from = c('a', 'a', 'b'), dest = c('b', 'c', 'd') )
#> df
    #from dest
#1    a    b
#2    a    c
#3    b    d
```

I want to group by `from` values and give a group number to each group. This is the expected result:

```
result = data.frame( from = c('a', 'a', 'b'), dest = c('b', 'c', 'd'), group_no = c(1,1,2) )
#> result
    #from dest group_no
#1    a    b        1
#2    a    c        1
#3    b    d        2
```

I can solve this problem using a for loop as follows:

```
groups = df$from %>% unique
i = 0
df$group_no = NA
for ( g in groups ) {
    i = i + 1
    df[ df$from == g, ]$group_no = i
}
#> df
    #from dest group_no
#1    a    b        1
#2    a    c        1
#3    b    d        2
```

I wonder if it is possible to solve this problem in a more elegant and functional way without using for loops? Specifically, I wonder if this can be done using `dplyr::group_by` function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `mutate` to add a column which is just a numeric form of `from` as a factor:

```
df %>% mutate(group_no = as.integer(factor(from)))

#   from dest group_no
# 1    a    b        1
# 2    a    c        1
# 3    b    d        2
```

Note `group_by` isn't necessary here, unless you're using it for other purposes. If you want to group by the new column for use later, you can use `group_by` instead of `mutate` to add the column.

Comment: No need to use group_by at all. df %>% mutate(group_no=as.integer(from))   The OP is going to the wrong direction.

Comment: Was editing to mention that as you commented...

Comment: Instead of `factor()`, consider using `fct_inorder()` or another `fct_` function to specify the factor order. `fct_inorder()` maintains the original order of the data frame whereas factor selects however the factor is ordered (alphabetically, perhaps)

Comment: You can create groups in the order of the vector like `forcats::fct_inorder(x)` with `factor(x, levels = unique(x))` if you like, but that's not part of the question. Generally speaking, row order doesn't mean anything and is often not guaranteed unless you explicitly sort first. If you're creating a factor to have a factor (not to create indices like here), you'll want to specify levels somehow.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `group_indices` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(group_no = group_indices_(., .dots="from"))
#     from dest group_no
#1    a    b        1
#2    a    c        1
#3    b    d        2
```

---

A similar option using `data.table` is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, group_no := .GRP, by = from]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `transform` from the base package

```
transform(df,group_no=as.numeric(factor(from)))

#   from dest group_no
#1    a    b  1
#2    a    c  1
#3    b    d  2
```

If the `from` column is already a factor you can remove the `factor()` function and use only

```
transform(df,id=as.numeric(from))
```